# GCC - Get the size of custom section without linker script

Tags: c, gcc

Is it possible to get the size of a specific (custom) section without a linker script?

I want to place function pointers in this section. It's for a bare-metal application. Want to implement a minimal module (driver) support. My goal is to call some sort of initialization code in this modules. The section size should be variable. Depending on the implemented modules. With the size from the section and the size from a single function pointer I can calculate the number of modules which are required to load.

I wrote the following macro, which places the function pointer in a specific section:

*linker.h:*

```
#define _ADD_FUNC_PTR(_section, _func) \
        int (*fp_ ## _func)(void) \
        __attribute__((section(#_section))) \
        = _func ;
```

The usage of the macro:
*module.c:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "linker.h"

int bar_init(void)
{
    printf("bar\n");
}
_ADD_FUNC_PTR(.modules, bar_init)
```

My current way is to get the size of this section via linker script and assembly code. Here small snippets:

Extract from my linker script:

```
    .modules :  {
        . = ALIGN(4K);
        _modules_s = .;
        *(.modules)
        _modules_e = .;
    } > RAM_KERN
```

The simple assembly functions (here AArch64) which I call in C:

```
FUNCTION(asm_modules_start)
    ldr x0, =_modules_s
    ret

FUNCTION(asm_modules_end)
    ldr x0, =_modules_e
    ret
```

With these two functions I can calculate the number of modules, which I can load. But my question is: Is this also possible without assembly?

Comment: This is implementation-specific.  However, I would be inclined to guess that you need to use linker script, because it is (I expect) the linker that determines the size of the section in the first place.

Comment: You certainly don't need the assembly.  You can simply do `extern char _modules_s[];` (or maybe without the leading underscore, depending on how symbol naming works on your platform) and then use `_modules_s` as a pointer in your C code.  But I agree with @JohnBollinger that I don't see how you can do without the linker script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this without assembler.

You need to declare the symbols as external:

```
typedef int (*function_pointer)(void);

extern function_pointer* modules_s;
extern function_pointer* modules_e;

size_t number_of_functions = modules_e - modules_s;
```

This works, because both pointer are from the same array.

Depending on your compiler system, you might need to remove the leading underscore, or not.